# Copy the latest version of an artifact from a Maven repository

Tags: maven-2, version

I am trying to copy a war file from my company's Nexus repository to a specific location. I am using **maven-dependency-plugin** in the following way:

```
    <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <id>copy-to-output</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>copy</goal>
    </goals>
   </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
               <artifactId>myproduct</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.0</version>
               <type>war</type>
               <overWrite>false</overWrite>
             </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
           <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/output</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The problem arise when I am trying to use **`<version>RELEASE</version>`** instead of a specific version (or no version at all) in order to get the latest release version (although not best practice, in this case it is safe) - it doesnt work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it work with a version range?

Comment: No, I tried [2.3.0,) with no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brian Fox (who wrote the dependency plugin) explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221758/does-the-maven-dependency-plugin-use-some-other-kind-of-artifact-resolution-than/1635038#1635038) that the `unpack` and `copy` goals do NOT support ranges (nor the LATEST or RELEASE) - he didn't implement this feature - and suggests to use the `xxx-dependencies` goals instead.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if this has been fixed in a later version of Maven; we're using 3.0.3 and maven-dependency-plugin:copy goal is working using `<version>LATEST</version`